# Pass by reference in class

Tags: c++

Im struggling with the following code. Will the statement `this->oEvent = oEvent;` copy or reference to oEvent?

```
class Test {
 private:
  map<string, string> oEvent;

 public:
  run( map<string, string> &oEvent ) {
    this->oEvent = oEvent;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will copy, as `Test::oEvent` is not a reference.

Comment: That was what I though. How would I solve this? By `map<string, string> * oEvent;` and `this->oEvent = oEvent;`? Was hoping to not use a pointer.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson How do you solve *what*? You haven't mentioned any problem.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson Yes it seems you might have to resort to using pointers, if you really want the member to be a "reference" (as "proper" C++ references has to be initialized by the constructor). But do `this->oEvent = &oEvent;`, to get the address of the argument.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson Regarding the comment from juanchopanza, you might want to read [about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There might be other solutions to your problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ops, forgot about that. I was trying to access the original oEvent object.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, I know. The ampersand flew away :P